# What is a "Unit Shock" in an Impulse Response Function?

Tags: impulse-response, autoregressive-model

Is a "one unit shock" in an impulse function of variable "temperature" a 1% increase or 1 more "unit" (1 degree)?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! I haven't heard the term "one unit shock", but [it appears to be used, for example, in Matlab.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.impulse.html). Can you give more context as to where you found a reference to "one unit shock" ?